# Grails left outer join between unrelated domains.(one way one to many relationship)

Tags: grails, hql, criteria, createcriteria

I am following [this](http://mrpaulwoods.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/implementing-burt-beckwiths-gorm-performance-no-collections/) link to bring some positive changes regarding performance in my app.

I have following two classes

```
class Topic {

    String title
    String body
    String type
    User user

    static mapping = {
        body type:"text"
    }
}
```

and

```
class Follower {
    Topic topic
    User user
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Keeping above two classes in mind, is it possible to write equivalent criteria for following query?

```
SELECT title,follower.user_ID,topic.id  FROM TOPIC 
left outer join follower on topic.id = follower.topic_id
where follower.user_id = 1 or follower.user_id is null;
```

I came up with following criteria which fails because there is neither reference of `follower` in `topic` nor I could find a way to swing this criteria to right join because there is no such criteria specification

```
def recentQuestions = Topic.createCriteria().list([sort:'lastUpdated',order:'desc',max:5]){
            createAlias  "follower", "f" , CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN

            or{
                eq('f.user',u)
                isNull('f.user')
            } 
            eq('type','FORUM',[ignoreCase: true])

        }
```

Comment: How are you creating an alias for `follower` when there is no `follower` in `Topic`?

Comment: @dmahapatro this is what the OP says in his question. He transformed the query in a criteria, but it fails exactly because Follower is not linked with Topic.

Comment: @Sap you will use pagination or just show the last 5 topics? A solution is to use HQL to perform your query.

Comment: Oops got it, sorry for misreading the question. I know I always screw up on a Friday. :( Thanks @SérgioMichels. Yea, HQL will be a better approach.

Comment: @dmahapatro Friday should be a beer day and not work :-)

Comment: @SérgioMichels Rightly said my dear friend. Something like [this](http://gr8conf.org/uploads/eu2013/Image/blogs/2013-05-09%2009.17.05.jpg) will make my weekend. ;)

Comment: Friday's over and I have a hangover:) Anyways, I was trying to avoid HQL because I thought they may backfire if I decide to use NOSQL like MongoDB or DynamoDB in future because GORM may not support them out of the box.